# Como melhorar o desempenho nesse código

Tags: c

Fiz a questão [A Lenda de Flavious Josephus](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1030), porém o estourou o tempo limite, o que eu posso mudar para diminuir o tempo

Meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>

void carregaVetor(int *vetor, int numero);
void removeNum(int *vetor, int *cont, int *tam, int *indice);
void removeElem(int *vetor, int *posicao, int *tam, int *cont);  
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

int vetor[90000], cont = 0, tam, indice = 0, posi;
int teste, numero, pulo, i;
while(scanf("%d", &teste) != EOF)
{
    for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &numero, &pulo);
        tam = numero;
        carregaVetor(vetor, numero);
        while(tam != 1)
        {
            cont = posi = indice = 0;
            while(indice != (pulo - 1))
            {
                removeNum(vetor, &cont, &tam, &indice);
            }
            cont = 0;
            while(cont != pulo)
            {
                removeElem(vetor, &posi, &tam, &cont);
            }
        }
        printf("Case %d: %d\n", i + 1 , vetor[0]);
    }
}

  return 0;
}

 void carregaVetor(int *vetor, int numero)
{
   int i;
  for(i = 0; i < numero; i++)
  {
      vetor[i] = i + 1;
  }
}

 void removeNum(int *vetor, int *cont, int *tam, int *indice)
{
   (*tam)++;
   vetor[*tam] = vetor[*indice];
   (*cont)++;
   (*indice)++;
}

 void removeElem(int *vetor, int *posicao, int *tam, int *cont)
{
   int i;
   for(i = (*posicao); i < (*tam); i++)
   {
       vetor[i] = vetor[i + 1];
   }
   (*tam)--;
   (*cont)++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para analisar este código, vamos aplicar algumas transformações:

1. Corrigir a indentação.
2. Colocar as declarações de variáveis no menor escopo possível.

   - A variável `tam` pode ser declarada onde ela recebe `numero`. E essa declaração pode ser movida para ficar imediatamente antes do `while (tam != 1)`.
   - As variáveis `numero` e `pulo` podem ser declaradas imediatamente antes do `scanf` que as lê.
   - A variável `indice` pode ser declarada no lugar onde é atribuído zero a ela.
   - As variáveis `i` podem ser declaradas no `for` onde são usadas.
   - A variável `posi` é utilizada apenas no `while` do `removeElem`. O valor dela é sempre definido como zero antes deste `while` ser executado. Logo, podemos mover a sua declaração para ficar imediatamente antes desse `while`. Dessa forma, o `while` fica assim:

     ```
     int posi = 0;
     while (cont != pulo) {
         removeElem(vetor, &posi, &tam, &cont);
     }
     ```
   - A variável `cont` é definida como zero antes do `while` do `removeNum` onde é usada e definida como zero de novo antes do `while` do `removeElem` onde é usada. Dessa forma, podemos trocar por duas variáveis diferentes declaradas cada uma antes do seu respectivo `while`.

     ```
     int indice = 0, conta = 0;
     while (indice != pulo - 1) {
         removeNum(vetor, &conta, &tam, &indice);
     }

     int contb = 0, posi = 0;
     while (cont != pulo) {
         removeElem(vetor, &posi, &tam, &contb);
     }
     ```
3. Podemos copiar e colar o corpo das funções `removeElem`, `removeNum` e `carregaVetor` de volta ao `main` para facilitar nossa análise e desmontamento do código. As variáveis `i` de `carregaVetor` e de `removeElem` são renomeadas para `j` para não colidir com a `i` já existente no `main`. As referências e desreferências a ponteiros são eliminadas. O resultado até aqui é isso:

   ```
           for (int j = 0; j < numero; j++) {
               vetor[i] = j + 1;
           }
           int tam = numero;
           while (tam != 1) {
               int indice = 0, conta = 0;
               while (indice != pulo - 1) {
                   tam++;
                   vetor[tam] = vetor[indice];
                   conta++;
                   indice++;
               }
               int contb = 0, posi = 0;
               while (contb != pulo) {
                   for (int j = posi; j < tam; j++) {
                       vetor[j] = vetor[j + 1];
                   }
                   tam--;
                   contb++;
               }
           }
   ```
4. Observe que a variável `posi` sempre tem o valor zero. De fato, a função `removeElem` lia o seu valor a partir do seu endereço, mas nunca escrevia nele. Assim sendo, você pode eliminar esta variável.
5. Observe que a variável `conta` (que é a `cont` do seu código original quando usada no `while` do `removeNum`) sempre tem o mesmo valor de `indice` e que o seu valor nunca é utilizado para nada. Assim sendo, ela pode ser eliminada.
6. Podemos reescrever os dois `while`s acima (os do `removeElem` e do `removeNum`) como laços `for`. O primeiro usa a variável `indice` como contador e o segundo usa `contb`.
7. O seu `while (scanf("%d", &teste) != EOF)` só será (ou deveria ser) executado uma única vez. Neste caso, não é necessário usar o `while`, basta usar o `scanf` sozinho. O seu problema também não precisa considerar entradas mal-formadas onde o número do `NC` do enunciado do problema não seria informado ou coisa assim, então você não precisa verificar o retorno do `scanf`.
8. O seu `while (tam != 1)` está assim:

   ```
       while (tam != 1) {
           for (int indice = 0; indice != pulo - 1; indice++) {
               tam++;
               vetor[tam] = vetor[indice];
           }
           for (int contb = 0; contb != pulo; contb++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < tam; j++) {
                   vetor[j] = vetor[j + 1];
               }
               tam--;
           }
       }
   ```

   - Observe que o `tam++` vai ser executado um número de vezes que é exatamente `pulo - 1`. Logo, você pode colocar um `tam += pulo - 1` após este `for` e substituir `vetor[tam]` por `vetor[tam + indice]`.
   - A variável `tam` é decrementada sempre que `contb` é incrementada. Neste ponto é possível concluir que ela será decrementada `contb` vezes e é possível colocar `tam -= pulo` depois do `for` do `contb`. O valor do `tam` no laço do `j` pode ser substituído para `tam - contb`. Neste momento teremos isso no código:

     ```
         tam += pulo - 1;
         for (int contb = 0; contb != pulo; contb++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < tam - contb; j++) {
                 vetor[j] = vetor[j + 1];
             }
         }
         tam -= pulo;
     ```
   - Podemos então trocar o `tam` do laço do `j` por `tam + pulo - 1`, eliminar o `tam += pulo - 1;` e trocar o `tam -= pulo;` por `tam--;`.
   - Com isso, podemos finalmente trocar o `while (tam != 1)` por um laço `for`.

O código resultante fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int vetor[90000];
    int teste;
    scanf("%d", &teste);
    for (int i = 0; i < teste; i++) {
        int numero, pulo;
        scanf("%d %d", &numero, &pulo);
        for (int j = 0; j < numero; j++) {
            vetor[j] = j + 1;
        }
        for (int tam = numero; tam != 1; tam--) {
            for (int indice = 0; indice != pulo - 1; indice++) {
                vetor[tam + indice] = vetor[indice];
            }
            for (int contb = 0; contb != pulo; contb++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < tam + pulo - 1 - contb; j++) {
                    vetor[j] = vetor[j + 1];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Case %d: %d\n", i + 1, vetor[0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Olhando-se o código resultante, vemos que ele tem uma alta complexidade pois temos um `for` dentro de um `for` dentro de um `for` dentro de um `for`. A operação que é executada um maior número de vezes é o `vetor[j] = vetor[j + 1];` que tem a finalidade de remover um elemento do meio do vetor e deslocar todos os elementos subsequentes. No laço do `indice`, a instrução `vetor[tam + indice] = vetor[indice];` também está a deletar elementos do meio do vetor.

Vetores não são estruturas que contam com remoção de elementos no meio como algo eficiente de se fazer, e portanto o melhor seria você procurar uma estrutura de dados que contasse com tal característica, o que sugere que a solução ideal seria feita por meio de listas dinamicamente ligadas (e talvez circulares).

Comment: Uma lista duplamente encadeada poderia tornar o codigo mais eficiente ?